AggregateRoot domain event on persist only and in new transaction
I have a AbstractBaseEntity which inherits from org.springframework.data.domain.AbstractAggregateRoot.
My entity Purchase inherits from this base entity and registers an event, before a new entity is persisted. (But not when it is updated.)
@PrePersist
public void createPersistEvent() {
    this.registerEvent(new DomainEvent(this));
}

This works fine, but now I listen to the fired events with this listener
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
class PurchaseEventHandler {
    private final PurchaseRepository purchaseRepository;

    @TransactionalEventListener(phase = TransactionPhase.AFTER_COMMIT)
    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public void onEvent(DomainEvent event) {
        //...
    }
}

which catches the event.
When debugging, I see that eventually after @PrePersist a new entity of Purchase is created. And AbstractAggregateRoot#domainEvents() is only called on this new instance and then returns an empty list. On the first instance, AbstractAggregateRoot#domainEvents() is never called.
All I want is to receive an event when a new instance of Purchase was successfully created and persisted in the database. This should happen async after the transaction was completed.
What is the right way to go?
